# FileSyncProvider Exception sourceDirectory is write protected for 'filesync.metadata'

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

in my program i have an exception, because i want to synchronize a local directory with a write protected networkDirectory.

Message:

```
Microsoft.Synchronization.MetadataStorage.MetadataStorageEngineException: Fehler bei einem Speichermodulvorgang. Fehlercode: 25039 (HRESULT = 0x80004005, Quellen-IID = {0C733A7A-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}, Parameter=(0, 0, 0, H:\filesync.metadata, , , )).
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Fehler bei einem Speichermodulvorgang. Fehlercode: 25039 (HRESULT = 0x80004005, Quellen-IID = {0C733A7A-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}, Parameter=(0, 0, 0, (sourceNetworkDirectory)\filesync.metadata, , , )).
```

I would like to avoid writing the 'filesync.metadata' to the sourceDirectory, or maybe change the path for writing the metaFile

Can someone help me?

Greetings from Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the constructor for the file sync provider allows you to specify an alternate location for the metadata file.